# error while installing elastic search -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, elasticsearch, information-retrieval

I have trying to install elastic search engine in my windows .. at first I download zip file, extract it and then write the command ..
after I getting some errors but I solved them this is the last error I get and can't solve  :

> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m,
> -Xms4020m, -Xmx4020m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2107637760, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.distribution.type=zip, --module-path=C:\elasticsearch-8.4.3\elasticsearch-8.4.3\lib, --add-modules=jdk.net, -Djdk.module.main=org.elasticsearch.server]

[image]

this is my `jvm.options file`

```
################################################################
##
## JVM configuration
##
################################################################
##
## WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. If you want to override the
## JVM options in this file, or set any additional options, you
## should create one or more files in the jvm.options.d
## directory containing your adjustments.
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/jvm-options.html
## for more information.
##
################################################################



################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## The heap size is automatically configured by Elasticsearch
## based on the available memory in your system and the roles
## each node is configured to fulfill. If specifying heap is
## required, it should be done through a file in jvm.options.d,
## which should be named with .options suffix, and the min and
## max should be set to the same value. For example, to set the
## heap to 4 GB, create a new file in the jvm.options.d
## directory containing these lines:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################


################################################################
## Expert settings
################################################################
##
## All settings below here are considered expert settings. Do
## not adjust them unless you understand what you are doing. Do
## not edit them in this file; instead, create a new file in the
## jvm.options.d directory containing your adjustments.
##
################################################################

-XX:+UseG1GC

## JVM temporary directory
-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}

## heap dumps

# generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java heap fails; heap dumps
# are created in the working directory of the JVM unless an alternative path is
# specified
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# exit right after heap dump on out of memory error
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

# specify an alternative path for heap dumps; ensure the directory exists and
# has sufficient space
-XX:HeapDumpPath=data

# specify an alternative path for JVM fatal error logs
-XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log

## GC logging
-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
```

this is my `elasticsearch.yml file` :

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Readiness ----------------------------------
#
# Enable an unauthenticated TCP readiness endpoint on localhost
#
#readiness.port: 9399
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: false

#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically      
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 18-10-2022 14:38:08
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled: false

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["SAM-SAM"]

# Allow HTTP API connections from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
http.host: 0.0.0.0

# Allow other nodes to join the cluster from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and mutually authenticated
#transport.host: 0.0.0.0

#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

and I have memory, I have 50GB free on C disk and 345GB in D

[image]

where is the problem? and how can I solve it?

Comment: It seems your Elasticsearch is getting an out of memory error. Could you give us more information about the amount of RAM available on you machine ?

Comment: `-XX:+HeapDum...` isn't an error message, that's the list of arguments supplied to the java runtime when starting elasticsearch. Is there anything else before or afterwards?

Comment: @zapl there's a lot of logs, but I can't catch where is the problem, this is my first time on it.. also when I type localhost: //9200 nothing appears

Comment: @zapl I updated the question with a full screen of loggers, can you check it please?

Comment: there's no error in there. How does the log end? `[INFO]` logs mean no error usually. `[ERROR]`, or warn, fatal, something like that indicates problems

Comment: @zapl so why localhost://9200 not working :( it's `This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.`

Comment: the address would be `http://localhost:9200/` the port goes after the hostname

Comment: What you are showing is the CPU but I can see that the ram is at 87%. You may need to start your elasticsearch with constrained RAM. using the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` params